# ORA-00932: Decode BLOB

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table with this column: `LOGO                BLOB`

and making this select

```
 DECODE (pro.holder_hidden,'T', null, com.LOGO) COMPANY_LOGO
```

I got an error

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got BLOB
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: It is just like it is mentioned.
The column pro.holder_hidden is a char column, and it is not possible to change the datatype on the run.

Comment: I don't pretend to change the datatype. If pro.holder_hidden == 't' logo is null else logo is logo

Comment: DECODE doesn't support the BLOB data type. So it tries to convert it to a character type. As far as I know, the same is true of the CASE expression. I don't if it is possible to achieve what you're trying.

Comment: `case pro.holder_hidden when 'T' then null else com.LOGO end` ?

Comment: The `CASE` statement will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work for you?

```
case pro.holder_hidden when 'T' then null else com.LOGO end
```